# I'm trying to make my navbar fixed when the user scrolls down, but when I scroll down it doesn't stay

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, navbar

I'm trying to make it so that when the user starts scrolling, the navbar becomes fixed at the top. I'm using vanilla javascript to add my fixed navbar class dynamically on a scroll event, and when I check the devtools the class is being added, but the navbar doesn't change, so I'm assuming the issue is with my CSS. Any help is appreciated.

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
// fixed navbar on scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 80) {
    navbar.classList.add(".navbar-fixed");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove(".navbar-fixed");
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.nav-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<div class="bg-img">
  <nav id="home" class="navbar">
    <div class="nav-container">
      <div class="nav-logo">Logo</div>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li>
          <a href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
</div>
<!-- END OF NAVBAR -->
```

Comment: When you use the `classList` property you don't need to add a `.` before the class. Try `classList.add("navbar-fixed")` and `classList.remove("navbar-fixed")`

Answer (score 0):

Pretty close, just remove the dot when you add and remove the classList of navbar:

```js
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
  // fixed navbar on scroll
  window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 80) {
      navbar.classList.add("navbar-fixed");
  } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("navbar-fixed");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const navbar = document.querySelector("#home");
// fixed navbar on scroll
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 80) {
    navbar.classList.add("navbar-fixed");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("navbar-fixed");
  }
  
});
```